# How to check for End-of-File using NSFileHandle's readabilityHandler?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilehandle

I am reading data from a `NSFileHandle` (from a `NSPipe`) using a `readabilityHandler` block:

```
fileHandle.readabilityHandler = ^( NSFileHandle *handle ) {
     [self processData: [handle availableData]];
}
```

This works fine, I get all the data I expect fed to my `processData` method. The problem is that I need to know when the last chunk of data was read. `availableData` should return an empty `NSData` instance if it reached end-of-file, but the problem is that the reachability handler is not called again on EOF.

I can’t find anything about how to get some kind of notification or callback on EOF. So what am I missing? Is Apple really providing an asynchronous reading API without an EOF callback?

By the way, I cannot use the runloop based `readInBackgroundAndNotify` method since I don’t have a runloop available. If I cannot get this to work with the `NSFileHandle` API I probably will directly use a dispatch source to do the IO.

Comment: Are you sure all write ends of the pipe have been closed? Regarding run loops, all threads will create a run loop on demand and you can run one yourself.

Comment: Yes, the pipe is properly closed. I did some more experimenting and the same thing also happens with other kinds of `NSFileHandle` instances. When reading from standard input or a regular file there also is no notification for EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you're out of luck doing this with `NSFileHandle` if you can't use `readInBackgroundAndNotify`.

Two solutions I see:

1. Create a runloop and then use `readInBackgroundAndNotify`.
2. Roll your own implementation using `dispatch_io_*`

Answer (score 3):

I personally compare current file offset with current file position and stop reading.

```
extension FileHandle {
    func stopReadingIfPassedEOF() {
        let pos = offsetInFile
        let len = seekToEndOfFile()
        if pos < len {
            // Resume reading.
            seek(toFileOffset: pos)
        }
        else {
            // Stop.
            // File offset pointer stays at the EOF.
            readabilityHandler = nil
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't understand why it's been designed in this way for a long time, but now I think this could be intentional.

In my opinion, Apple basically defines `FileHandle` as an infinite stream, therefore, EOF is not well defined unless you close the file. `FileHandle` seem to be more like a "channel".

It's also unclear what happens if another process appends/delete some data to/from the file while you're reading from it. What would be the EOF in this case? As far as I find, there's no mention about this case in Apple documentation. As far as I know, there's no true exclusive file I/O lock in macOS like other Unix-like systems.

In my opinion, `availableData` can return empty data at any time if I/O is not fast enough, and `readabilityHandler` just don't care about EOF.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the accepted answer is actually incorrect. The readabilityHandler is indeed called when EOF is reached. That is signaled by having availableData be of 0 size.

Here’s a simple playground that attests to this.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

let pipe = Pipe()
pipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { fh in 
    let d = fh.availableData
    print("Data length: \(d.count)")
    if (d.count == 0) {
        fh.readabilityHandler = nil
    }
}
pipe.fileHandleForWriting.write("Hello".data(using: .utf8)!)
pipe.fileHandleForWriting.closeFile()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: I experience the same behavior. This is how I've been detecting EOF and it has been working consistently.